# ngx-datatable-footer does not work in Angular Aplication

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

In my angular application was installed the ngx-datatable component, when mounting a test I got it simple everything occurred as expected, however when using the ngx-datatable-footer element I was returned the following message:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   'ngx-datatable-footer' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'ngx-datatable-footer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ngx-datatable-footer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress > this message. ("
>
> ```
>     [ERROR ->]<ngx-datatable-footer>
>       <ng-template
>         ngx-datatable-footer-template>
> ```
>
> "): ng:///GeneAppModule/ProcessoFormComponent.html@567:8
>       at syntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:170688:34)
>       at TemplateParser.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:181808:19)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:195960:39)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:195880:62
>       at Set.forEach (native)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:195880:19)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:195767:19
>       at Object.then (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:170677:148)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:195766:26)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:195695:37)

Code works:

```
<ngx-datatable
  class="material"
  [rows]="rows"
  [columnMode]="'force'"
  [footerHeight]="100"
  [headerHeight]="50"
  [rowHeight]="'auto'">
  <ngx-datatable-column name="Ordem" prop="ordem" [width]="75">
    <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
      {{column.name}}
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
      {{value}}
    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

Code does not work:

```
<ngx-datatable
  class="material"
  [rows]="rows"
  [columnMode]="'force'"
  [footerHeight]="100"
  [headerHeight]="50"
  [rowHeight]="'auto'">
  <ngx-datatable-footer>
    <ng-template
      ngx-datatable-footer-template>
      <div style="padding: 5px 10px">
        TESTE
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-footer>
</ngx-datatable>
```

Version in my package.json:
"@angular/core": "^4.2.2",
"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "7.2.1",

Comment: You mean 'does not' in the title I guess?

Comment: Sorry, 'does not work'

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are only changing this code you show here? I literally copy-pasted your code below another ngx-datatable in a component of mine and I see your datatable perfectly.